# MSSQL: Get results from select in same row

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, resultset

At first let me explain you my DB construct.

I use MSSQL with the sqlsrv driver of php.

I have two DB tables Names and AccountFieldValues.

Names has a variable field NameID and a fix field StringValue.
This table contains all names of the accountfield variables ergo: FirstName,LastName etc.

AccountFieldValues has the same variable field FieldNameID,FieldValue and IdentityID.
This table contains the content of the accountfield variables for every user.

Now to get a specific variable content of the user with the IdentityID=10 and the StringValue='FirstName' you can create a query like that:

```
SELECT FieldValue FROM AccountFieldValues 
WHERE IdentityID=10 AND FieldNameID IN (SELECT NameID FROM Names WHERE StringValue='FirstName')
```

Or with a inner join

```
SELECT ACF.FieldValue FROM AccountFieldValues ACF
INNER JOIN Names N ON (N.StringValue='FirstName' AND N.NameID=ACF.FieldNameID)
WHERE ACF.IdentityID=10
```

When you want a single variable content both methods work well.
But now comes the problem, when i want to get multiple variable contents in one query this gets tricky.

I can expand the two queries like this:

```
SELECT FieldValue FROM AccountFieldValues 
WHERE IdentityID=10 AND FieldNameID IN 
(SELECT NameID FROM Names WHERE StringValue='FirstName' OR StringValue='LastName')
```

And the other query like this:

```
SELECT ACF.FieldValue AS 'FirstName', ACF2.FieldValue AS 'LastName' FROM AccountFieldValues ACF
INNER JOIN Names N ON (N.StringValue='FirstName' AND N.NameID=ACF.FieldNameID)
INNER JOIN AccountFieldValues ACF2 ON (ACF2.IdentityID=ACF.IdentityID)
INNER JOIN Names N2 ON (N2.StringValue='LastName' AND N2.NameID=ACF2.FieldNameID)
WHERE ACF.IdentityID=10
```

Although ugly as hell in comparison with the upper method this will give me the result of FirstName and LastName in one Result Row. like this:

```
FirstName|LastName
------------------
Foo      |Bar
```

On the other hand the first Method will give me a result looking like this:

```
FieldValue
----------
Foo
Bar
```

This isn't desirable because i cannot fetch the wanted AccountFieldValues for every user in one resultset

Is there a method to get the result of the tables like with the ugly joins but faster and easily expandable like the first method?

Comment: This is a [Entity-attribute-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a way to pivot your data. Here is one using conditional aggregation:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/70a11/2/0)

```
SELECT
    FirstName   = MAX(CASE WHEN n.StringValue = 'FirstName' THEN acf.FieldValue END),
    LastName    = MAX(CASE WHEN n.StringValue = 'LastName' THEN acf.FieldValue END)
FROM AccountFieldValues acf
INNER JOIN Names n
    ON n.NameId = acf.FieldNameId
WHERE acf.IdentityId = 10
GROUP BY acf.IdentityId
```

This is a not dynamic. You can also remove the `JOIN` on `Names` and use the `acf.FieldId` in your `CASE` instead. Like this:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN acf.FieldId = <FIELD_ID_OF_FIRSTNAME> THEN acf.FieldValue END)
```

---

In case you want a dynamic approach, here is one way using dynamic sql:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/70a11/3/0)

```
DECLARE @sql1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @sql2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @sql3 NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

DECLARE @identityId INT = 10

SELECT @sql1 = 
'SELECT
    acf.IdentityId' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN acf.FieldNameId = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.FieldNameId) + ' THEN acf.FieldValue END) AS '
     + QUOTENAME(n.StringValue) + CHAR(10)
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT FieldNameId FROM AccountFieldValues WHERE IdentityId = @identityId
)t
INNER JOIN Names n ON t.FieldNameId = n.NameId

SELECT @sql3 =
'FROM AccountFieldValues acf
INNER JOIN Names n
    ON n.NameId = acf.FieldNameId
WHERE acf.IdentityId = @identityId
GROUP BY acf.IdentityId'

DECLARE @finalSql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SET @finalSql = @sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3

EXEC sp_executesql @finalSql, N'@identityId INT', @identityId
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I didn't know you can add multiple query in one query this works really well!

Answer (score 1):

I'm usually doing it this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Names AS N
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN N.StringValue='FirstName' THEN AFV.FieldValue END)
        , MAX(CASE WHEN N.StringValue='LastName' THEN AFV.FieldValue END)
    FROM dbo.AccountFieldValues AS AFV
    WHERE AFV.FieldNameID = N.NameID
    ) AS AFV(FirstName, LastName);
```

And you can easily add new rows in `CROSS APPLY` there. It's pretty much a `PIVOT` as [Felix Pamittan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2203084/felix-pamittan) said.